# How to set the style for border of gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

in the following is my gridview and i want to delete all borders.

How could be this possible to do? because i tried a lot but couldn't got succeeded.

[image: gridview]

Comment: 2 ways. You can do this with design view click on the gridview and choose Gridlines:both to Gridlines:none  or give the grid a cssclass and the n`border:none`

Comment: its doing its job thnx

Comment: No problem :) i'll set is as awnser so you can check it as marked

Answer (score 3):

You will have to Add `RowDataBound` event in GridView control:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        TableCell tCell = e.Row.Cells[2];
        tCell.Attributes["style"] = "border-right:0";
    }
```

Also Try With

```
<ItemStyle border="0" />
```

With Properties:

```
BorderStyle>>RowStyle:none
```

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: how can i do this by using gridview properties and also for the row borders, because i don't want to have the vartical inline borders

Comment: well, what is problem with this? i will look at properties, wait.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the property "GridLines" to "none" of the gridview? It should make it.

Otherwise, you could try to to create as CSS Class ;

```
<style type="text/css">
    .MyClass {
        border:none // As @DiederikEEn said.
    }
    .MyClass td{
        border:none // As @DiederikEEn said.
    }
</style>
```

And set a the CssClass of your gridview like that :

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" id="myGridView" CssClass="MyClass">
     [...]
</asp:GridView
```

Answer (score 1):

2 ways. You can do this with design view click on the gridview and choose Gridlines:both to Gridlines:none or give the grid a cssclass and the n`border:none`